# Item from ListView is stuck to my cursor

Tags: listview, vb6

[image: Image of the ListView with the item stuck]
After clicking something from a ListView box the item clicked becomes stuck to the cursor and the only way to free the cursor is to terminate the application.

The way the item leaves the list and follows the cursor is undesireable

`item.selected = false` fails

How do I prevent it from sticking to the cursor?
or failing that how do i unstick it?

Comment: Can you show us the code associated with the listview and all it's events?

Comment: Try setting `OLEDragMode` property to `Manual`.

Comment: i actually fixed it, but i cannot post the answer yet, `OLEDragMod` property to `Manual` worked along with a few extras i think. thanks @wqw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@wqw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40691/wqw) was correct; setting the `OLEDragmode` property of the `ListView` to `Manual` worked a treat.